# Getting horizontal distorted lines after reprojecting a polygon layer to Eckert IV using .to_crs()

Tags: python, coordinate-system, polygon, geopandas

I need a projected shapefile and my extent is whole globe. I am getting the horizontal lines with Eckert IV, Robinson and Mollweide. I need shape and area preserve accurately. How to reproject or how to get rid of these distorted horizontal lines.

Code Snippet:

```
file_path = 'C:\Files\Tasks\ProximityAnalysis\Data\RawData\kba_2022_10\KBA_IBAT_Triggers\KBA_IBAT_Triggers_POL.shp'
gdf = gpd.read_file(file_path)
gdf= gdf.to_crs("ESRI:54012")
gdf.plot()
```

[image]

Comment: You *can't* preserve both shape and area correctly on a global map.  https://www.google.com/search?q=Can+a+map+be+both+conformal+and+equal-area

Comment: projecting using geopandas vs arcmap software is giving very different area in m^2. How to deal with it

Comment: The horizon clipping code is probably different. Splitting your features into eastern and western sections may help.

Comment: With splitting the data into east and west part from 0.0 longitude, still getting the same horizonal distortion lines in both east and west shapefile

Comment: Split at +/-180 (aka date line)

Comment: Splitting at +/-180, and then converting it to eckert IV, still shows the horizontal lines.

Comment: Then the code is buggy and you shouldn't trust the area it generates.